# where can i keep settings for my tfs extension

Tags: javascript, .net, plugins, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to write a plugin for TFS 2015 (its important). I read a couple of manuals. the examples all turns out simply, but it is more difficult with a real plugin. my problem: where can i keep settings for my tfs extension?

I want to move requests addresses from the code in the some type settings(they will be the same for all users), so that during work, I could quickly change them without changing the plug-in code. but i cant find any solution of this problem.

i find this info: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/data-storage but it still keep settings in code.

I will be grateful for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I totally got your point. You just need to change your own code with the settings of your extension and publish to TFS. Then all user on the client side using your extension will automatically update the setting. Then don't need to manually change the code or update.

---

Update

Unfortunately, this is not support for now.  You have to through the code to change the settings and rebuild, package the extension. Update/ install and test your extension.

Comment: I wanted to find out if some external storage options, not to keep all the settings in the extension code

for example I have a service address: http://myservice.com/myapi and if I want to change the address of the service I did not have to change the code and rebuild extension

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not support for now.  You have to through the code to change the settings and rebuild, package the extension. Update/ install and test your extension. To debug it in local has been suggested as a uservoice and reviewing  by TFS PM. If this feature is support will reduce mountains of work.